# Does combining silicone gel therapy and pressure therapy help scar reduction (vs. using just one of these therapies)?

Tags: dermatology, scar-tissue-scars, cosmesis

The 2015 review {1} mentions different therapies for scar reduction, including:

| Treatment | Description | Advantages | Disadvantages |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Pressure therapy | Application of elastic bandages or pressure garments to apply pressure to scar sites. | Noninvasive. Can be applied at home by the patient. | Often cause discomfort to the wearer which affects compliance. To achieve optimum results from pressure therapy require 6–12 months constant wear. |
| Silicone gel therapy | Application of silicone gel sheets or gel formulated in a tube. | Noninvasive. Can be applied at home by the patient. | To achieve optimum results from silicone gel therapy require 6–12 months constant wear. |

Does combining silicone gel therapy and pressure therapy help scar reduction (vs. using just
one of these therapies)?

---

References:

- {1} Bleasdale B, Finnegan S, Murray K, Kelly S, Percival SL. The Use of Silicone Adhesives for Scar Reduction. Adv Wound Care (New Rochelle). 2015 Jul 1;4(7):422-430. doi: 10.1089/wound.2015.0625. PMID: 26155385; PMCID: PMC4486716. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4486716/